# What websites are linking to JLU?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

What websites are linking to JLU?

By keeping track of this information, we will be able to think of new places where links to JLU would be appropriate.

*Background:[JLU's Area51 status](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language-usage) is surprisingly similar to ["Jewish Life and Learning"'s status](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning) and they recently asked this question. Both JLU and JLL have good statistics except for visits/day. JLU is extremely useful, I really hope it makes it out of beta, so let's make it more popular via incoming links.*

Answer (score 2):

Diamond moderators have access to information about how users are getting linked to our site.  Across the top of this page, though, is a big banner that says "analytics data is intended for moderators only; please don't share the specifics of this data in public," so I can't go into too much detail here.

I will say that the top linker is currently StackOverflow, followed by Google.  Social networking and bookmarking sites account for another chunk, and then blogs and forums for Japanese language learners.

If a lot of our traffic is coming from automated StackOverflow advertising, we don't have a lot to be proud of.  So get out there and spread the word!  If you got an interesting answer to your question, tweet it, blog it, put it on Facebook, put it on reddit.  If someone on a forum or blog has a question that's answered here, give them a link!  Tell your friends, tell your language partners.  Be excited about what we have here, and get the word out!

Comment: Thanks Amanda! Mostly from English-language websites? How about from Japanese-language websites, and websites in other languages such as German, Spanish or French?

Comment: @Nicolas English websites, except for one Swiss site in German.

Answer (score 2):

I found this site via [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/ij3ld/japanese_stackexchange_a_community_of_students/)